# column does not exist error when using a variable in postgresql copy in function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have this postgresql function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_select_test(_id bigint)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$                

BEGIN
        copy (select sub.id
        from (
          SELECT id FROM sim s where id = _id) sub) TO '/tmp/results.tsv';
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION sp_select_test(bigint)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I run

```
select * from sp_select_test(264);
```

I get error - column "_id" does not exist

If I replace the variable _id in the function with a value say 264, the function works. That is if instead of id = _id I use id = 264

Any reason why the function is failing?

Comment: try $1 instead of _id

Comment: Get "there is no parameter $1" message

Comment: ah, I see now :) use dynamic query instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_select_test(_id bigint)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$                

BEGIN
        execute $$copy (select sub.id
        from (
          SELECT id FROM sim s where id = $$||_id||$$) sub) TO '/tmp/results.tsv'$$;
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION sp_select_test(bigint)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: What's the logic behind that?